# How to access email resource path in Keycloak?

Tags: themes, keycloak

I am customizing the email template for password-reset. I wish to access the logo from **email**  resources directory (i.e) **\themes\\email\resources\img\marketing.jpg**

This can be possible for **login** module via ***${url.resourcesPath}***

Some one please point out me how to access the email resource path in password-reset.ftl

version **keycloak-4.0.0.Final**

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a custom plugin within **Keycloak 4.3.0.Final** to address a specific issue. Following that, I made a contribution to the Keycloak community, which ultimately led to the resolution of the problem in Keycloak version 8.0.0.

**${url.resourcesUrl}** works from

> **keycloak version 8.0.0**

You can find the details of this contribution in the following GitHub pull request:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/6512

Regarding the usage of the **ftl** file, you can incorporate the provided code snippet to embed font and image resources:

```
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('${url.resourcesUrl}/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.eot');
  }
</style>
.
.
.
<img src="${url.resourcesUrl}/img/company_logo.svg" alt="logo">
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this problem myself, and after some searching I found [this email thread](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-December/012532.html):

> Hi community,
>
> I am looking for a way to add images to custom keycloak email themes. Our company template HTML uses the images sent as attachment. I would therefore like to attach the required images to the email. If this is not possible, what would be the correct way to add images to the HTML template?
>
> Unfortunately the current documentation does not state anything of it:
> http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/server_development/topics/themes.html
>
> Regards
> Jonathan

> I don't think you can do this out of the box today, but you should be able
> to create a custom email sender provider that does it. Look at docs for
> details on creating custom providers (as well as quickstarts on examples).
> Then look at EmailSenderProvider and the implementations in our repo.

> Hi,
> If your goal is to display a kind of logo or some image in the mail, you
> can include it as an embedded image using
> `<img src="data:image/png;base64,.... "/>`
> It's not perfect as some email clients (like gmail) don't display this kind
> of image but it can do the trick before finding a better solution.
> BR, Jérôme.

> Hi,
>
> Thanks for your suggestions. After reading a lot about email client support for image embedding in emails (e.g. the solution from Jérôme is blocked by Outlook), I think the best solution is to implement my own email sender provider and link the images to the attachments (using CID) .
>
> @Stian Thorgersen: My understanding is that I will have to override the EmailTemplateProvider based on the FreemarkerEmailTemplateProvider (or can I just extend from this one?) to fetch attachments from a path e.g. /attachments/ and pass them to the EmailSenderProvider, am I correct?
>
> Regards
> Jonathan

So, whilst [the documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_development/#images) says you can use `<img src="${url.resourcesPath}/img/image.jpg">` in your custom themes, this doesn't actually work for email templates.

**UPDATE (2022):** The documentation has changed over time, so this *might* be possible now, though I haven't verified that: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#adding-an-image-to-a-theme

Comment: Still the same for 19.0.3
<img src="${url.resourcesPath}/img/image.jpg">
"url" is not defined on all email types.
Fails for sendSmtpTestEmail

Comment: Still the same for 22

Answer (score 1):

I have Keycloak version 21. This code was working for fine:

```
<img width="188px" height="64px" src="${url.resourcesUrl}/img/logo.png" />
```

and full path to image is `themes/theme_name/email/resources/img/logo.png`